# How to disable driver certificate verification in Windows 10

Tags: drivers, windows-10, certificate

I just built a new machine and need to load an older driver for one of my 44" Designjet printers, but Win 10 will not allow either the driver for Win 7 64-bit or for Win 8 64-bit because they lack a proper digitally signed certificate. Never had this issue in Win 7.

I tried using the shift/restart technique to access the Troubleshoot/Advanced Options/Startup Settings page where option #7 is to disable the certificate verification, but it doesn't seem to work. After selecting option 7 with the F7 key there is no verification of my selection, the computer just starts its reboot. This seems a little odd. Anyway even after trying this several times I still get the verification errors when trying to load one of the drivers.

Is there any known way around this? I see a bunch of certificate functionality on the god mode screen, but I have no idea how to use any of that.

Thanks for any help.
Jim

Comment: Have you followed [this](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5470-driver-verifier-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found these instructions in a [Microsoft forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/how-to-i-turn-off-digital-signature/a7047647-bf29-468f-a885-8e23d60f3daa):

1. Click start, and type gpedit.msc
2. ENABLE the option for code signed drivers at:
3. User Config/Admin Templ./System/Driver installation
4. then set the drop box to "Ignore"

Comment: Thanks for your rapid response. I performed the steps as you suggested, rebooted and tried to install one of the drivers. Still no joy. Same certificate error. This one's a real PITA.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem was that I hadn't disabled the Win 10 Auto Driver Install. The OS didn't like me trying to install the archaic Win 7 64-bit driver over the auto installed brand new generic Win 10 driver.

Once I did that and removed the printer from the installed printer list, rebooted and then added the printer again, the "Have Disk" option worked just fine and now I have a fully functional HP driver installed.

Thanks for the help I received.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Start -> Run -> GPEdit.msc
Now go to User Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Driver Installation -> Code signing for drivers

Click on "Disabled", then on "OK".